# 'GHUnitIOS/GHUnit.h' file not found in Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios6, compiler-errors, gh-unit

Hello this is the error that I got I am trying to use 
ASIHTTPRequest API. I have Xcode 4.5.2 with IOS 6.0 simulators.

I've tried to search this file on my mac but actually the file does not exist in my entire hard drive!
Any plausible way to fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me.

1. Go to Frameworks and click GHUnitIOS.framework
2. Be sure that Utilities view is enabled
3. On Target Membership uncheck the target then build
4. Check again the target and build or run

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem.

You might add the test class to the main application target. Uncheck the target and then, the error "GHUnit/GHUnit.h file not found" disappeared.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you should know whether you follow the document below:

http://gabriel.github.com/gh-unit/docs/appledoc_include/guide_install_ios_4.html

and then you need to check the GHUnitIOS framework in the xcode, can't you see some ".h" files below the "headers" group? if not, may be the GHUnitIOS framework is not proper.go to location  "/GHUnitIOS.framework/Versions/A/", and copy all the 3 files in it, go to the location "GHUnitIOS.framework/", paste them and then run the test project. is that ok?

if you can see those ".h" files in the framework, maybe the build settings is not properly set.
you should check the search path.

Answer (score 0):

Choose GHUnitIOS-.zip if our app is based on iOS device or choose GHUnit-.zip if our app is base on Mac OS X.

download page: https://github.com/gh-unit/gh-unit/downloads